# Is it Haram to bet on fixed games/matches?

Tags: gambling

Assalam Aleikum. 
I have a question to anyone who has a better understanding on this and please feel free to shade light on this..I know a source where people bet on fixed matches /games and win, which some of my friends do.. But my question is, I know Betting is Haram but is this type of gambling haram coz there's no big risk on the outcome? & What if you plan to give the winnings to charity? I always have a feeling I can do much in my poor community with this kind of money but afraid of falling into the bad side while doing the good. Shukran.

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. Please consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help] for further information on our site and model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no matter how big or small it is, betting is betting and it's always haram. if you do anything to win something and others lose it's haram, you can do other things to help poor people instead of this, i hope you find different things instead